# What is a javascript "[ <3 empty items> ]" structure?

Tags: javascript

I expect this JS:

```
(new Array(3)).map(_ => 3.14)
```

... to yield `[3.14, 3.14, 3.14]`. Instead, it yields `[ <3 empty items> ]`. My questions:

1. What on earth "is" this weird structure I've created? It would make sense to me if it were e.g. `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, but I don't know of a primitive JS structure called `<empty item>`. It's clearly not the same as `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, because the latter would have yielded `[3.14, 3.14, 3.14]`.
2. How can I succinctly create an array `[3.14, 3.14, 3.14]`?

Comment: `new Array(3).fill(3.14)`

Comment: you can do `new Array(3).fill(3.14)`. If not you can fill it with `undefined` and then use `.map` like `new Array(3).fill(undefined).map`